# Concurrent modification exception within synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I made some modifications on my multithread program and started to get `ConcurrentModificationException` s at an object's `HashTable`, so I made all accesses to this `HashTable` into `synchronised` methods to avoid concurrent accesses to my object, unlike my expectation it didn't solved the problem. Here is a outline of the design used:

First I've got a `JTable` that displays some data of an usb device, this `JTable` asks for a communication-core object that implements `Observer` (the one that reads and writes data to my device) through an `Observable` object the data it wants, the data it wants depends of which rows are displayed so it's updated when the user scrolls de table, than this communication-core object gets this notification through `synchronized update` method that calls other `synchronized` method that updates a `HashTable` which saves the last read values for after use (this communication class notifies back my `JTable` class and other objects when it reads values though other `Observable` object). The exception is occuring in this last method while updates the `HashTable`. Here is a simplification of the code:

The following methods are of the communication-core object

```
public synchronized void update(Observable o, Object arg)
{
    // do some other work
    // calls the second synchronized method
    updateMonitorList();
}

private synchronized void updateMonitorList()
{
    // updates a list of monitoring addresses (no problem here)
    // m_lastValues is the HashTable that is giving me headaches
    Iterator<Parameter> itr = m_lastValues.keySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        // removes the currently not used parameters from the HashTable
        Parameter p = itr.next(); // concurrent exception here WHY? :/
        boolean contains = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_monitorList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (p.equals(m_monitorList.get(i)))
            {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!contains)
        {
            m_lastValues.remove(p);
        }
    }
    // more operations with the HashTable
    for (int i = 0; i < m_monitorList.size(); i++)
    {
        // adds newly added parameters to the hashtable
        boolean contains = false;
        for (Observer key : m_requestedParameters.keySet())
        {
            if (key.equals(m_monitorList.get(i)))
            {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!contains)
        {
            m_lastValues.put(m_monitorList.getAt(i), m_monitorList.getAt(i).m_intUserSetting);
        }
    }
}

// this method is used to know if a value has changed
private synchronized boolean getParameterChanged(Parameter currentParamer)
{
    Integer v = m_lastValues.get(currentParamer);
    return v == null || v != currentParamer.m_intUserSetting;
}
```

I need this approach because I have multiple windows that asks for values from the usb device, and this communication object takes care of it, there was no problem with concurrency before I added this `HashTable` of last values. This `m_lastValues` `HashTable` is not used in any other method not listed above.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**[ EDIT ]**

Actually that was not a multithread problem, it was just a misunderstood exception meaning. As @Tudor pointed out the problem was the `remove()` method inside the `while` loop. Here is how I solved it:

This code goes into `updateMonitorList()` method, note that `no Iterator was needed` (the first question was with a `for` loop like that), actually the `Iterator` made no difference:

```
    ArrayList<Parameter> remove = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
    for (Parameter p : m_lastValues.keySet())
    {
        boolean contains = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_monitorList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (p.equals(m_monitorList.get(i)))
            {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!contains)
        {
            remove.add(p);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < remove.size(); i++)
    {
        m_lastValues.remove(remove.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: "The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the Hashtable is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException." ([Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html))

Comment: "Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. **For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.**" ([ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for (Parameter key : m_lastValues.keySet()) // exception this line
{
    // removes the currently not used parameters from the HashTable
}
```

The problem is here. You can't change the collection while iterating over it, regardless of synchronization. It is a single-threaded issue actually.

What you can do is either switch to an [explicit iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and use `remove()` or save the items to remove in a separate collection and remove them afterwards.

```
Iterator<Parameter> iter = m_lastValues.keySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Parameter current = iter.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_monitorList.size(); i++) {
        if(current.equals(m_monitorList.get(i)) {
            iter.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you guys are awesome, I'll try that out. That concurrent exception put me in the wrong direction, I acctually thought that it could be a problem but I was not sure and just forgot that too :)

Comment: +1 HashTable is a legacy class IMHO If you use ConcurrentHashMap instead it doesn't get ConcurrentModificationException and doesn't use `synchronized` ;)

Comment: @Tudor please check out my question again, I made modifications in the code and still get the exception.

Comment: @HericDenis: That's because you are still using a `for` loop. I'll post a snippet in a second.

Comment: thanks @Tudor! I have no idea why the code identation messed up after edit :/

Comment: forget about the identation, that was my old browser using compatibility mode -.- I'll try it @Tudor

Comment: Well, I fell idiot for that last code, now I see what I've done. BUT I expected it was going to work now, but check above @Tudor

Comment: I am using a for loop, but it is iterating over the list not the parameter hashtable

Comment: @HericDenis: Well your code still has the same problem: you are calling `remove` inside the `for` loop. Use the `while` loop and `iter.remove()` I posted.

Comment: Well, I think I'm just not in a good mod to program today -.- I didn't use your code because the logic it's not what I need just that. I solved my problem I'll post is there.